# UK Visa Rejection - Second Time

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

My first application was refused in October 2018 and I have resolved all the reasons as per the refusal letter during the second.

I applied again for a UK visit visa in Feb 2019 with all necessary documents and got the refusal letter as below.

I provided six months worth of bank statements which include two months of salary from my old employer for August'18 and September'18 and four months salary from October'18 to January'19.

Expenses as per the application form is only the living cost per month. I paid for my car 3,100 GBP and 6 months house rent 3,200 GBP in advance resulting in a low opening balance. These payments were not included in the application as one is an asset purchase. Monthly rent is included in expenses.

When do you suggest for me to apply again?
What points to improve again on the same?

[image: Refusal Letter]

Comment: Based on your stated income and expenses your bank balance should be increasing at SAR 21,250 - 10,870 = 10,380 per month. Thus over the 6 months your closing balance is expected to be SAR 6,000 + 6 * 10,380 = 68,280.  Can you explain the difference between this and your actual closing balance of 44,846?

Comment: @k2moo4 Presumably the difference is due to the OP paying fir his car and six month’s rent in advance. However, this should have been clear from the bank statement if the payments went through the account. If this is the explanation the OP could reapply, and provide evidence of the two transactions. However, with two refusals in under 6 months it would not be wise to risk a third so soon, so it may be better for the OP to wait say 6 months before reapplying.

Comment: @Traveller The difference is due to the Car and House Rent. Car Payment is made through Bank where as the Rent payment is in Cash to the Real Estate Office. My Wife got visa and it is expiring on 31 July 2019. Hence i cannot wait for Six month before reapplying if i want to travel with her.

Comment: @Traveller I paid 14,000 upfront and Paying balance as Monthly Installment. Rent I paid 15,000 upfront and i have included the monthly portion in expense.

Comment: @user92669 There’s something that doesn’t reconcile. The ECO isn’t questioning the low opening balance (explained by your upfront car and rent outgoings). They are questioning why the apparent excess of income over expenditure during the previous 6 months that you’ve stated in your application is not reflected in your bank statement. Did you and your wife state that you’d be travelling together in your respective applications?

Comment: @Traveller Please note two things. I havent explained the Rent Advance and Car Payment as i did'nt find a relavent coulmn.

Comment: Secondly, I joined the new Job at a higher Salary for Four Months which was stated in Employment Letter. To reconcile the balance, the old Salary for two months need to be considered.

Comment: Please note my Bank statement of Six Months include Two months Salary from Old Employer and Four Months from New Employer

Comment: @user92669 Please edit your question to include all the extra information you’ve provided in your comments

Comment: _My Wife got visa and it is expiring on 31 July 2019. Hence i cannot wait for Six month before reapplying if i want to travel with her_  Entry clearance officer does not care about that. You will **very likely** be refused again even if you address this very issue. You’re looking desperate unfortunately.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn What is your suggestion?

Comment: Give it time and space, one year. Or get a good immigration attorney. Three refusals in a row will essentially finish you off.

Comment: See the three linked posts at the top of the page. They all contain useful information. Then strongly consider retaining a UK immigration lawyer to help you sort this out. While this looks to me like it's just a matter of a few missing documents, an immigration lawyer can ensure you have the highest chance possible of approval, or advise you if it truly is unwise to apply again.