# Can I use a mortgage loan paid by my employer as source of funds for my Uk visitor visa application

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I want to attend 5 days of training in the UK, I have two accounts, in one of my accounts (savings) I transferred a mortgage loan deposit by my employer into my salary account. I intend to use the money for personal development and company setup rather than property. Do you envisage me having any visa challenge with this?

Answer (score 3):

You’ll have to prove the source of the money when submitting your bank statements [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) If the loan document from your employer says its purpose was for a property purchase then yes, IMHO it will be a problem and will very likely be viewed as a type of funds parking strategy [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158)

It would be much better from a visa application point of view to be able to demonstrate that you can afford the trip without this money (from salary and savings). This question [UK Visa Rejection - Second Time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132731/uk-visa-rejection-second-time) is an example of how closely UKVI can examine an applicant’s financial position.

Comment: My employer would consider use of a mortgage or car loan for something else as gross misconduct.